# Some difficulties interpreting this complex sentence

Tags: grammar

> Musk championed a larger systemic vision, a vision for a **bottom-up emergent order** of other interested parties-whether companies, individuals, or governments-to utilize the new and radically lower-cost transport infrastructure to build up a sustainable human civilization on Mars, **potentially, on numerous other locations around the Solar System, by innovating and meeting the demand that such a growing venture would occasion.**

I would start with second part in bold. The first part I guess just mean a group (="order") of client for Musk's companies (government, individuals...). "Bottom up emergent", I don't know what it means.

Ok, yeah that is the first part in bold. But the REAL confusion is the second part in bold. First, I understand the "civilizations are built on Mars", but I don't understand they have to add "potentially, on numerous other locations around the Solar System". I guess it would be better if they were to add "and" before "potentially". Because as is, the phrase sounds like those "locations" are on Mars.

Finally, the last part,"by innovating...". I think this describes how Musk champion the vision. By kinda confusing that it's all the way at the end.

Answer (score 2):

**Bottom-up** refers to proceeding from the bottom of a hierarchy to the top in this context. **The bottom-up emergent order** alludes to the related companies making progress through their individual endeavors that, as a whole, push the goal forward. This is a sort of strategy, where those in the lower parts of the hierarchy are individually making progress, aims to amplify and add momentum to their individual achievements as their achievements are funneled upwards and combined by those that oversee them. This **bottom-up emergent order** means that, by acquiring the right people, this phenomenon will happen (=emerge) naturally, as a pattern, which is both ideal and will continue.

The second part is a synonym for saying that his vision ,as it pertains to Mars, could potentially be extended to other planets given time and continuing to innovate and meet the demand of such a growing company.